# Show/Hide table columns with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I wanted to set a cookie in browser for shown/hidden columns, As setting changed so that table didn't get reset on page refresh.

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/HvA4s/72/

**HTML**

```
<a href="edit" id=edit>Show/Hide Columns</a>
<table id=table>
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th id="name">Name</th>
        <th id="street">Street</th>
        <th id="number">Number</th>
    </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Freddy</td>
        <td>Nightmare Street</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Luis</td>
        <td>Lost Street</td>
        <td>3456</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    var headers = $('#table th').map(function() {
        var th =  $(this);
        return {
            text: th.text(),
            shown: th.css('display') != 'none'
        };
    });

    var h = ['<div id=tableEditor><button id=done>Done</button><table><thead><tr>'];
    $.each(headers, function() {
        h.push('<th><input type=checkbox',
               (this.shown ? ' checked ' : ' '),
               '/> ',
               this.text,
               '</th>');
    });
    h.push('</tr></thead></table></div>');
    $('body').append(h.join(''));

    $('#done').click(function() {
        var showHeaders = $('#tableEditor input').map(function() { return this.checked; });
        $.each(showHeaders, function(i, show) {
            var cssIndex = i + 1;
            var tags = $('#table th:nth-child(' + cssIndex + '), #table td:nth-child(' + cssIndex + ')');
            if (show)
                tags.show();
            else
                tags.hide();
        });

        $('#tableEditor').remove();
        return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

Let's say I hide column 1, column 2 using the button. But columns get visible again as page refresh. Is there a way we can use cookie to keep the setting as is, until changed manually using the same options.

Comment: Try `jquery.cookie.js`

Comment: @Morpheus How that will work in my case? Can you please put some code in fiddle.

Comment: Here is a quick mock-up -> http://jsfiddle.net/HvA4s/78/. It looks like it doesn't set the cookie properly, but you should be able to figure out.

Comment: @Morpheus this is not working properly, and i was not able to figure out what to change. Can you please help out?

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/HvA4s/89/

Comment: @Morpheus Yes it's working but, Check box is showing checked where column is hidden. However it should be checked when column is visible and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [jquery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
$('#table th').each(function ($index, $elem) {
    var $cookie = $.cookie(this.id.toLowerCase() + ".shown");
    $index = $index + 1;
    $('#table th:nth-child(' + $index + '), #table td:nth-child(' + $index + ')').css('display', (typeof ($cookie) === "undefined" || $cookie === "true") ? "" : "none");
});

$('#edit').click(function () {
    var headers = $('#table th').map(function () {
        var th = $(this);
        var $cookie = $.cookie(th[0].id + ".shown");
        return {
            text: th.text(),
            shown: th.css('display') != "none"
        };
    });

    var h = ['<div id=tableEditor><button id=done>Done</button><table><thead><tr>'];
    $.each(headers, function () {
        var $shown = this.shown;
        h.push('<th><input type=checkbox', ($shown ? ' checked ' : ' '),
            '/> ',
        this.text,
            '</th>');
    });
    h.push('</tr></thead></table></div>');
    $('body').append(h.join(''));

    $('#done').click(function () {
        var showHeaders = $('#tableEditor input').map(function () {
            return this.checked;
        });
        $.each(showHeaders, function (i, show) {
            var cssIndex = i + 1;
            var tags = $('#table th:nth-child(' + cssIndex + '), #table td:nth-child(' + cssIndex + ')');
            var $id = $('#table th:nth-child(' + cssIndex + ')')[0].id;

            if (show) {
                $.cookie($id + ".shown", "true");
                tags.show();
            } else {
                $.cookie($id + ".shown", "false");
                tags.hide();
            }
        });

        $('#tableEditor').remove();
        return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvA4s/98/)

Comment: This is correct now, One more question : You are using th.id to set cookie, How can i use the th tag text instead id. Because asp.net grid view does not have id parameter in table>th

Comment: Please ignore my ask, I was able to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

**JSfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/ZakirSiddique/qazsdbc0/5/
**[HTML Table Header Show/Hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUkDs.png)**

```
**HTML **
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<body>
<table  border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td> Cell 1 <i Title="Hide" class="fa tbtn fa-times">X</i></td>
        <td>Cell 2 <i Title="Hide" class="fa tbtn fa-times ">X</i></td>
        <td>Cell 3 <i Title="Hide" class="fa tbtn fa-times">X</i></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr class="del">
    <td>Row 0 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 0 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 0 Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="del">
    <td>Row 1 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="del">
    <td>Row 2 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="del">
    <td>Row 3 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="del">
    <td>Row 4 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 4 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="del">
    <td>Row 5 Column 0</td>
    <td>Row 5 Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 5 Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="show"> Show all</button>
</body>


</html>
```

**Jquery**
 $(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("thead td .tbtn").click(function () {

        caaell = parseInt(this.parentElement.cellIndex + 1);
      //  alert(caaell);
        $('td:nth-child(' + caaell + ')').hide();
    });

    $("#show").click(function () {         
        $('td').show();           
    });
});
```

**CSS**
     .tbtn {
        cursor:pointer;
        float:right;
        padding:3%;
            font-size: 13px;
    font-family: monospace;

```
}
    .tbtn:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    }
thead{
      background: #184a74;
color: white;

}
```